# Style a specific wordpress article with CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, styles

How to apply css style to a wordpress article without being administrator?

I've [found](http://codex.wordpress.org/CSS) [plenty](http://digwp.com/2010/02/custom-css-per-post/) of [information](http://thethemefoundry.com/blog/html-wordpress/) on google, but none that apply to my case because:

1. I'm **not an administrator** of the site so changing the theme, the global stylesheet, or hacking the php to allow html `style` tags is unfortunately not an option.
2. I only want to change the style of **only some articles**, so even if I had the authorization I'm not interested in changing the default stylesheet.

Currently, the only solution I've found is using `style` attributes html tags of interest, but it is error prone and doesn't scale well.

Any suggestion on including css style rules either inline or from an external url?

Comment: Go ask it here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Even though it's not valid HTML, I believe you _can_ use a `link` element inside the `body` of the page. So you could write your CSS, upload it somewhere and then link it in the article. Regarding only styling some articles; most themes ID the articles like `<article id="article-12">` so simply target the IDs you need to style.

Comment: Sorry for off-topic, I flagged my question to be moved.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, style tags within posts **do** work (testing in WP 3.5.1 using the text editor).
However, you have to be cunning with the styling to make sure you override the defaults. An easy way to do this is with the `important` notation:

```
<style type="text/css" scoped>
* {
color:red!important;
}
</style>

<h1> hello </h1>
```

All the content of the post ("hello", in this case) appears red.

The use of the `scoped` attribute means the styles only apply to the blog post, not the whole page.

Comment: Note that the `scoped` attribute doesn't work anywhere atm: http://caniuse.com/#search=scoped. Edit: Instead, simply prefix each selector with the ID of the article: `#article-12 * {color: red}`. Shouldn't need the `!important` rule then either.

Comment: Well no, I obviously tried that but here in 3.4.2 `<style>` tag and everything inside gets killed  by the visual editor...

Comment: Are you restricted to the visual editor? Try only using the plain text.

Comment: @powerbuoy scoped is at least supported in Chrome 25.0.1364.172 - shouldiuse seems a bit out of date. But a valid point nonetheless!

Comment: @jaypeagi: no, I have 2 tabs: visual & html. But by default it opens in visual and removes my style tag. Indeed as long as I stay in html it works. But it's frustrating that style gets removed each time I or a proof-reader opens it in visual mode.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about changing your specific posts that you create only?

If so, I'm guessing you only have access to the posts in question and therefore it would make it very difficult for you to do anything scalable.

You said you can't change the stylesheets or change the default stylesheet but if you could then you could wrap all the articles you want the specific styling on inside their own div with an id name of your choice. This would then automatically change all elements inside post with your div id and would scale across all pages you create without the need of re-defining the rules every time, for example:

```
<div id="antoines-article">
All your content
</div>
```

Your only other option is to use inline styles

```
<div style="background-color: green">All your content</div>
```

or by adding this before your post content (bare in mind however that this is only allowed by default to Administrator and Editor roles)

```
<style>
div { background-color: green; }
</style>
```

The difference here is that the first rule would only change the div it is attached to while the second would change all your divs to green.

This still may not be what you are after but I'm afraid from what you've said you are pretty limited with your options.

In addition using the !important tag after most css definitions will overwrite CSS styles from stylesheets if you find something wont change for you. For example

```
div { background-color: green !important; }
```

In addition, you could ask the webmaster of your site to setup specific page templates with different CSS styles loaded which you could then hook onto.

Comment: 3rd option doesn't work (the `<style>` tag)

Comment: Maybe this is because you are not an administrator. I've just tested this on my test WordPress site and `<style>` tag does work fine in both visual and text editors. Maybe its blocked for non-administrators though. What about any of the other suggestions?

Comment: I just tried this as a contributor and you're right, it strips out the `<style>` tag for Authors and below. Maybe you could ask the administrator to allow this for you?

Comment: Other suggestions are valid, but the first one (div id) just postpones the problem: I still have to style `#antoine-article`. Indeed asking the admin is obviously the logical solution but I was hoping to avoid that.

Comment: I understand you wanting to avoid that but unfortunately without having some sort of master control, you can't really do something apart from what is mentioned above.

Comment: Inline style works as I stated in my question, but it's not exactly user-friendly... If I decide to change `h2` color, I'll have to change all `h2`s styles.

Comment: You will definitely need the site webmaster to help you with this I'm afraid. Your user role and capabilities just won't allow something like this currently, sorry.

Comment: Well I'll try asking the admin, not sure I'll have more success than with wordpress filters though -;) Thanks~

Comment: Sorry I can't be of any more help Antoine, I wish you luck!